# Assigning one of a <p:selectOneMenu> item in java object

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, converters, managed-bean, selectonemenu

I have a list of governorates that I displayed in a `<p:selectOneMenu>`

the java code in the managed bean:

```
public List<SelectItem> gouvernorats() {
    List<Gouvernorat> all = emetteursEJB.findAllGouvernorat();
    List<SelectItem> items = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Gouvernorat g : all) {
       items.add(new SelectItem(g, g.getLibelleGouv()));
    }
    return items;
}
```

in the `<p:selectOneMenu>` I add `<p:ajax>`:

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{emetteurBean.selectedGouvernorat}" style="width:160px"  >  
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />  
    <f:selectItems value="#{emetteurBean.gouvernorats()}" />  
    <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{emetteursBean.handelGouvChanged()"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

in the method `handelGouvChanged()` `selectedGouvernorat` object is always `null`;

Recently I added the convert I stumbled upon `NullPointerException`

```
@FacesConverter(forClass = Gouvernorat.class)
public class EmetteursConverter implements Converter {

    @EJB
    private ReferentielDaoLocal refEJB;

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String selectedValue) {
        System.out.println("Inside The Converter");
        System.out.println(selectedValue.length());
        if (selectedValue == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return refEJB.findGouvByCode(selectedValue.trim());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        if (value == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return String.valueOf(((Gouvernorat) value).getIdGouvernorat());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This specific construct won't work without a `@FacesConverter(forClass=Gouvernorat.class)` without causing conversion error (and thus never hitting the ajax listener method), so you must have a converter. Apparently it returned `null` in `getAsObject()`. Show it in your question if you don't have a clue how to fix it.

Comment: @BalusC how I can do it ,public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        //how I can do here
    }

Comment: Just edit your question to show the converter code you currently have. Then we can point out the mistake. With the code as shown so far in your question (assuming that it's obviously already in a form), the ajax listener can impossibly be invoked without a converter, but yet you confirmed that it *is* invoked, so you *must* already have a converter. So, just edit the question and copypaste the converter's code in.

Comment: frankly @BalusC believe me i do'nt have a conveter in my code 
and I have not worked with it.

Comment: Well, then apparently the input component is not been placed in a form component. But this is a too obvious mistake.

Comment: i placed it into  <h:form id="MasterForm" style="display: block" >

Comment: @BalusC i add the Converter

Comment: FacesConverter is not eligible for dependency injection until the JSF 2.2 release, so your EJB is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, I injected EJB with `InitilContext.lookup ()`

```
@FacesConverter(forClass = Gouvernorat.class)
public class GouvernoratConverter implements Converter {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(GouvernoratConverter.class.getName());

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String selectedValue) {

        if (selectedValue == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            try {
                ReferentielDaoLocal myService = (ReferentielDaoLocal) new     
                InitialContext().lookup("java:global/ErpCCF/ErpCCF-ejb/ReferentielDaoImpl");
                return myService.findGouvByCode(selectedValue);
            } catch (NamingException ex) {
                LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, "Converter Gouvernorat Error", ex.getMessage());
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        if (value == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return String.valueOf(((Gouvernorat) value).getIdGouvernorat());
        }
    }
}
```